# Open Xamarin IOS app from registred URI Scheme

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to open Xamarin IOS application when clicking on link with my scheme. I have followed this tutorial: https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/. The solution generally works, but problem occurs when application is already opened. Clicking on link stops application and starts again. Is it expected behavior? How to pass link to application without killing it? I want to use URI scheme solution because it already works across other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found source of the problem - the base method **UIApplicationDelegate.OpenUrl** should not be called. It throws exception with message: "Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown."